# Trouble understanding OOP in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

Can someone please explain to me the difference between this two different writing :

```
var Box2DInt = {};
    Box2DInt.boot = function (game) { };
    Box2DInt.boot.prototype = {
         preload: function () {

         },
         create: function () {

       }
    }
```

AND

```
var boot=function(game){};
boot.prototype={
   preload:function(){

   },
   create:function(){

   }
}
```

Comment: Have you run them and looked as the results they produce?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these create a constructor function (although they use anonymous functions and assign them to variables/properties without a Capitalised first letter, which isn't best practise).

One stores the resulting function in a variable.

The other stores it as a property of an object.

There's no difference in the functions themselves.

Comment: the only difference is that if i want to call boot in the first method i should do this : `Box2DInt.boot` and in method 2 i should do this : `boot.`